# SASM issues - fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, gcc, ide, assembly

I use fedora33 as OS, and I come across an issue when using SASM. Even if I have installed GCC, NASM and FASM, when running the "hello world" samples SASM outputs error messages. Only 32-bit NASM assembler works fine, all the other assemblers, e.g. 64-bit NASM, 32-bit and 64-bit FASM and GAS assemblers give me compile errors. What should I do in order to fix this problem?

Comment: Showing some source code, commands, and error messages will help potential answerers understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the suitable assembler was not selected by default. I.e., when I opened the "hello world" project for FASM x64, the selected compiler was still NASM x86.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]